# Why am I getting the error Missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some very simple code but I am getting the aforementioned error, any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
function changeSlides(new_slide) {

    ${'#app_dev'}.toggle('blind', 500);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `${'#app_dev'}` to `$('#app_dev')`

`$` is a function and needs to be called like one.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses instead of curly brackets for the $ method:

```
$("#app_dev").toggle("blind", 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use paras

```
function changeSlides(new_slide) {

    $('#app_dev').toggle('blind', 500); //switch { to )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector function uses parentheses `()` not curly brackets `{}`

```
function changeSlides(new_slide) {

    $('#app_dev').toggle('blind', 500);

}
```

Comment: More generally, Javascript function access uses parentheses, not curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong brackets, it should be: `$('#app_dev')`